# Change back to old Certificate-Viewer in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, certificate, chromium, ssl-certificate

How can I change my Google Chrome/Chromium-based web-browsers to open the old certificate viewer, the one built-in to Microsoft Windows instead of the "new" Chromium one?

Old (goal) Windows Certificate Viewer:

[image: Windows Certificate Viewer]

([src](https://adamtheautomator.com/windows-certificate-manager/))

New (currently) Chrome Certificate Viewer:

[image: Chrome Certificate Viewer]

([src](https://news.softpedia.com/news/chrome-os-team-experimenting-with-a-certificate-section-in-the-page-info-pop-up-516719.shtml))

#### What I've tried

- I tried setting the chrome flag `chrome://flags/#chrome-root-store-enabled` to disabled and enabled but it didn't change the viewer.
- I couldn't even find the technical terms for both of these viewers in a web search or on Stack Exchange

Answer (score 1):

See here for the reasoning behind the new certificate viewer:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/net/data/ssl/chrome_root_store/faq.md

> In Chrome 105, Chrome on Windows and macOS transitioned from using the native platform certificate viewer to the Chrome Certificate Viewer. This transition promotes a consistent experience across platforms as we begin the rollout of the Chrome Root Store.

It is the same now in all Chromium-based browsers.

Comment: Thanks for linking me to a official article, now I know at least how to search.

So it seems like there is no (longterm) "workaround"/setting to change back to the old/Windows Certificate Viewer.

Which makes sense when the trust/root store is built-in to chromiums. At least now I know that.

Comment: Thanks again, Google. Now I have no way to check why (and which cert in a chain) is actually invalid and have to export it to my PC to check that natively...